# A question about the countable union of a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X\ne\emptyset$ a set, $f\colon X\to [0,+\infty)$. We consider
\begin{equation}
A_n=\{x:f(x)\le n\}.
\end{equation}

Clearly, $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$, then 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n.
\end{equation}

Can I say the following thing?

\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n =\{x:f(x)<+\infty\}=\{x:0\le f(x)<+\infty\}=X.
\end{equation}

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, all the equalities are absolutely right.

Comment: As you have defined f(x) to be non-negative, you can do that